# Why does JavaFX display some control characters?

Tags: java, javafx, unicode, fonts

I noticed JavaFX, JDK 1.8.0_131 displays control characters on Windows (7) as different symbols.

Here are the symbols displayed for characters 128-159:
[image: Here are the symbols displayed for characters 128-159]

[Pasting this to IntelliJ sees a similar result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWGrr.png), so it seems to be the Font, but I can not reproduce the same thing with Courier New in a non-java application:

Why is this happening and how can I change this behaviour?

To reproduce:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ControlCharsJavaFx extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ControlCharsJavaFx.launch(ControlCharsJavaFx.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextField textfield = new TextField();
        textfield.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 500%");
        for (int i = 128; i <= 159; i++) {
            textfield.setText(textfield.getText() + (char) i);
        }
        Scene test = new Scene(textfield);
        primaryStage.setScene(test);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ascii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only defines 128 characters, the first 7 bits of a word. Above 128, developers saw an opportunity to use these "empty" characters for something more useful. However, [thousands of developers had this same idea without any real standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII). So what you're seeing is probably your locale-specific encoding being rendered.

Ensure that you decode the encoding of your text, then re-encode as utf-8.

Comment: Java uses Unicode, Windows does too. This seems to be mainly the difference between CP1252 and ISO-8859-1, but what you wrote doesn't really have much to do with the problem here.

Comment: @Joey Doesn't matter if Java uses Unicode *output* if the wrong *input* encoding is being guessed. Hence the suggestion to explicitly decode the input text's original encoding.

Comment: Have you read the code? The source code is ASCII; the string with those characters is being built at run-time and thus absolutely is Unicode.

Comment: @Joey And evidently it is not being decoded (presumably by `TextField`) as if it were unicode. Otherwise mojibake would not occur. Unless the user's font is to blame, this is absolutely an encoding problem.

Comment: I updated my question because IntelliJ looks similar. It looks like it's the font, but using the same font (Courier New) in another application doesn't produce the symbols.

Comment: My guess here would be that JavaFX follows what browsers are doing and interpreting text that's not non-Latin1-Unicode as CP1252. But the text property is still a Java string and thus Unicode. There is no `byte[]` to apply any encoding to.

Comment: @Joey Yes, I believe you're right about it following browser convention. I attempted to find a means of explicitly specifying JavaFX decoding and could not find one, so I'm not sure there's a simple fix. Perhaps with more english text, the encoding will be guessed correctly, but this particular example probably requires a different gui system to produce correct output.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found out how to change this, but it seems to be a setting deeper inside Windows, which falls back to Windows-1252: In that charset, some of the control characters are mapped to visible characters, as can be seen in my question. This "issue" seems to appear in every windows program, e.g. also in Notepad.